# powershell - MS-Word document parsing - Get a table's caption text

Tags: powershell, ms-word, office-2007

I am parsing a word 2007 using powershell. I would like get each table's caption and print it to screen.

Here is an idea of what I would like to do, but the print caption line does not work.

```
$wd = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$wd.Visible = $true
$doc = $wd.Documents.Open($filename)
foreach ($table in $doc.Tables)
{
      #print table caption
      Write-Host $table.Caption.Range.Text #This does not work

      #Print Table contents
      foreach ($row in $table.Rows)
      {
          Write-Host $row.Range.Text
      }
}
```

Is it possible to get the caption associated with a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captions aren't properties of table objects, they're just text. You could do something like this for finding table captions, though:

```
$style = $doc.Styles | ? { $_.NameLocal -eq 'Caption' }
$wd.Selection.Find.Style = $style
$wd.Selection.Find.Text  = 'Table'  # if table captions are labeled "Table"
$wd.Selection.Find.Execute()
```

Since wildcard matches are non-greedy in Word, you may have to do something like this:

```
$style = $doc.Styles | ? { $_.NameLocal -eq 'Caption' }
$wd.Selection.Find.Style = $style
$wd.Selection.Find.Wrap  = 0
while ($wd.Selection.Find.Execute()) {
  if ($wd.Selection.Text -like 'Table*') {
    # do stuff
  }
  $wd.Selection.MoveRight()
}
```

The above matches just by style, so it should select the entire caption. The `MoveRight()` unselects the caption afterwards, so the next iteration will find the next match until the end of the document, where the search stops (`.Find.Wrap = 0`).

Comment: This selects the text 'Table' in the first caption. How would I go about getting all the text of the caption and iterating through all captions.

This selects the text 'Table' in the first caption. How would I go about getting all the text of the caption and iterating through all captions.